# Objects appear normal in material preview but in rendered mode with cycles they're encased in weird material blobs

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, displacement, bump

[EDIT: I'm pretty sure this was just a weird glitch. I switched to 'bump' as the node, then back to displacement, and it went away. Really odd but anyway. Maybe this can help someone else]
I'm new to Blender but I've tried everything I can think of, looked for answers online, and found nothing. The objects I'm using as particles look fine in the internal material preview mode, and when I move to the cycles rendered mode the outline still selects and looks fine, but they object is surrounded and encased in a strange blob structure that is uneditable/unselectable. It doesn't appear to be part of the mesh?? It changes shape slightly when I modify the displacement of the noise texture I have applied to it, but won't go away unless I delete the displacement, so I'm pretty sure it's resulting from that node. Also, it's only happening to the two objects I duplicated from the original one, on the far left.[image]
[image]
[image]
Please go easy on me, I'm brand new and this is only my third foray into the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'blob' happens when you set high *Midlevel* in the *Displacement* node.
Yours is set to 4,2 (default is 0,5)

- The 'blob' cannot be selected, because it's just displaced polygons
- It only happens in Cycles preview, because Eevee preview doesn't support displacement
- *Noise texture* only suplies values 0-1, so high midlevel may look weird

> **Displacement Midlevel**
>   Neutral displacement value that causes no displacement. With the default 0.5, any lower values will cause the surfaces to be
>   pushed inwards, and any higher values will push it outwards.
>
> *Blender Manual*

[image]